Segment Fault (Core Dumped) error when Running Android Emulator - Linux Ubuntu
I have installed android studio yesterday on my Linux Ubuntu.
it had  an emulator Pixel Fold API 35  installed with it.
the emulator  successfully launches, but shows this message, also the screen is blank :
Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.  As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer.  Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available

here are the some logs from terminal:
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoI0822 13:16:21.826052   28621 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
cannot add library /home/saad/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
cannot add library /home/saad/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: failed
added library /home/saad/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: SwiftShader Device (Subzero)
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
WARNING: could not open libX11.so, try libX11.so.6
I0822 13:16:21.924363   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
I0822 13:16:21.924399   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: false
I0822 13:16:21.924404   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
I0822 13:16:21.924409   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
I0822 13:16:21.924413   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
I0822 13:16:21.924417   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
I0822 13:16:21.924423   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
I0822 13:16:21.924437   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
I0822 13:16:21.924445   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
I0822 13:16:21.924449   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
I0822 13:16:21.924454   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
I0822 13:16:21.924469   28621 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
I0822 13:16:21.925752   28621 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc.)
I0822 13:16:21.925762   28621 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)
I0822 13:16:21.925768   28621 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)
I0822 13:16:21.925784   28621 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
I0822 13:16:21.925793   28621 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
INFO    | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Google Inc.)]
INFO    | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)]
INFO    | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)]
INFO    | Sending adb public key 
INFO    | Configuring second built-in display with width 1080 and height 2092 for pixel_fold device
WARNING: cannnot unmap ptr 0x77f431801000 as it is in the protected range from 0x77f166400000 to 0x77f431a00000
pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 20b400000
INFO    | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO    | Using security allow list from: /home/saad/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1000/avd/running/28621/jwks/b4c8efd8-8644-4d92-9c4d-92bc0ada3399/active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning /run/user/1000/avd/running/28621/jwks/b4c8efd8-8644-4d92-9c4d-92bc0ada3399 for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_28621.ini
I0822 13:16:22.061537   28668 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 2208 h 1840 dpiX 420 dpiY 420
I0822 13:16:22.061583   28668 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
INFO    | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
INFO    | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Google Inc.)]
INFO    | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)]
INFO    | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)]
INFO    | Activated packet streamer for bluetooth emulation
qemu-system-x86_64: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
WARNING | Error -5 while loading VM state
WARNING | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
WARNING | Failed to load snapshot, because 'emulation engine failed'; Emulator will delete existing snapshot and do a cold boot instead... 
INFO    | Deleting snapshot default_boot



I tried creating more emulators with the same API but none of them works
When Running them  i get this message :```the emulator process for AVD has terminated```
this is the log when running from terminal:
 ./emulator @Pixel_6a_API_35
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-saad/emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 28400
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/saad/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-35/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-saad/emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 28400
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_sleep_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_unfold_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoI0822 13:13:00.042701   28400 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

there are many similar question and I tried all solutions but none are working.
also i don't know why Pixel Fold launches but others don't.

Posting pictures of truncated messages is suboptimal. We cannot scroll right to the interesting (variable) parts of the messages. Rather, copy and paste the whole text into your Question, and bracket the text with <code> ... </code>.

"Segmentation fault" is the Unix/Linux way of saying "Illegal Memory Access". Your program tried to access an out-of-bounds memory address. Experience suggests location 0x00.
The rest of the message "(core dumped)" is good news! A long, detailed report has been written to a file in the /var/crash/ directory. Read it with less or more.
Are you missing a library? That could cause a jump to 0x00. Look at ldd $(type -p emulator).
